# Question about Z12≃Z4⊕Z3 generators and order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I apologize in advance for my messy language and questions; I've only been studying group theory for a month and thus these concepts aren't clearly locked in yet; hence my questions. :)

Take Z12≃Z4⊕Z3.

Call the generator of Z12 "a", Z4 "b", and Z3 "c".  Thus:

Z12 = aaaaaaaaaaaa

Z4 = bbbb

Z3 = ccc

Q1):  Am I using the term "generator" correctly as in "a single element whose repeated application generates the group"?

However, the automorphic generators of Z12 are {1,5,7,11}.

Q2)  Is "a" a generator since repeated applications of it produce Z12 or is the set {1,5,7,11} the generators since they are coprime to Z12?  How do I reconcile these two usages of the term "generator"?

Since Z4 and Z3 are characteristic subgroups of Z12, then:

b = aaa

c = aaaa

if we denote a= 1, then b = 3 and c = 4.

Q3) Is that construction correct?  If so, what is the group theory concept behind building a "child" generator from a repeated application of the "parent" generator?  In other words, is there a formal group theoretical concept that "ranks" the generators such that "a" is rank 1, "b" is rank 3, and "c" is rank 4?

Finally, I want to find a way to combine both b and c generators such that I get a new generator that would have rank 7.  I don't think the direct product works since I read that as a cartesian product (a,b) =ab = 12.  Instead I want a summation, a direct sum, where [a,b] = a+b = 7.  It seems like a direct sum is involved but I thought that direct products and direct sums where the same thing for abelian groups

Q4) I suspect this may be non-sense, but is there a way to combine Z3 and Z4 or interpret their direct product or sum such that we get a group of order 7 since there are 3 elements in Z3 and 4 elements in Z4??

Comment: It seems to me that the direct product/sum is related to the intersection of the two subgroups. I think what I'm looking for in Q4 would be the union of both those subgroups. Does this seem like the right Avenue to pursue? How are the union and the intersections of these subgroup related? And how would the union of Z3 and Z4 affect its representation of the parents structure of a Z 12? –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}/12$ is cyclic, and it is generated by any element prime to $12$, which as you have noted is $\{1,5,7,11\}$. So any of these elements could be the $a$ that you selected as your generator. For example, if you selected $5$, you would get
$$ 5, 5+5 = 10, 5+5+5 = 15 = 3, 5+5+5+5 = 20 = 8,$$
and so forth. You will see that you get all twelve elements of $\mathbb{Z}/12$ in sequence.

Now, if $a$ is any generator, then $12\cdot a = 0$, so that $3\cdot (4\cdot a) = 0$. That means that $4\cdot a$ generates a subgroup of order $3$ ($\{4\cdot a, 2\cdot (4\cdot a), 3\cdot (4\cdot a) = 0\}$). So this subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/3$. Thus you can select $4\cdot a$, where $a$ is any generator, for your $b$. Similarly, $3\cdot a$ generates a subgroup of order $4$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4$.

In general, if $G$ is cyclic of order $n$, with generator $g$, then $G$ has a (unique) subgroup of order $d$ for an divisor $d$ of $n$, and a generator of that subgroup is $g^{n/d}$ (or, if you wish to write your group additively, $\frac{n}{d}g$).

A group of order $12$ cannot have a subgroup of order $7$, since by Lagrange's Theorem the order of any subgroup divides the order of the group.

Finally, in general if $a, b\in \mathbb{Z}/12$, then the order of the subgroup generated by $ab$ is the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: "So any of these elements could be the a that you selected as your generator."
Thank you so much!  That clears that up nicely!

Comment: Followup...
Z2 is also a subgroup... call it's generator d=aa.
If I crafted the following using established Z12 generators...
e=dadddad...
then is there any group theoretical way to relate this back to Z12?

Comment: Let $d = 2$. Since $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, then $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is generated by $\frac{n}{d}\cdot 1 = 12 / 2 = 6$. You can check this: in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ you have elements $6$ and $6 + 6 = 12 = 0$, the identity.

Comment: Well, $d = a^2$, so $dadddad = a^2aa^2a^2a^2aa^2 = a^{12} = e$, which all makes sense in $\mathbb{Z}/12$. I think your notation is really holding you back from understanding what is going on. If you choose to write $\mathbb{Z}/12$ additively, $aa$ is written $2a$ (meaning $a+a$). Otherwise, it's written $a^2$.

Comment: You are really a huge help Roger.  Thanks again. :) I'm motivated by music theory.  There, we have 12 note chromatic scale (Z12) from which 7 (Z7?) are chosen to make a major scale, both of which are cyclic.  The "a" corresponds to a half-step; the "d" to a whole-step; and what I spelled above was a certain scale of WHWWWHW (dorian mode).  So is the takeaway that my spelling is not really Z7, but it's Z12 all along?  If so, how could I refer to the fact that the 7 notes chosen from 12 are cyclic if not Z7?  By your statement, I feel "compactificaton" may be a keyword.

Comment: You can certainly refer to them that way, and it makes sense, but they are *not* a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/12$ --- the sum of two of your elements is not again in that set, if the sum is performed inside of $\mathbb{Z}/12$.

Comment: Thanks to your help, it seems I was wrong in using Z2 = a^6 a^6 when what I want is Z6 =a^2 a^2 a^2 a^2 a^2 a^2.  Hence what I want to say is "A Z7 group created using Z12 (a) and Z6 (a^2) subgroup generators"...  Any problems with that wording?